# How can add a condtion to Yii CDbCriteria select?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I use this codes.
I want check if budget < 0 select it.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('*', 'SUM(amount) as budget');
$criteria->group = 'user_id';
$debtors = Transactions::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

How can i add this condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->select = array('*', 'SUM(amount) as budget');
$criteria->having = 'budget < 0 ' ;
$criteria->group = 'user_id';
$debtors = Transactions::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: tank you. but when i add this line.i have a error. https://1drv.ms/i/s!ArgubT4lADlRplEgjqItmsTx5FYN

Comment: I think u need 'SUM(amount)' instead 'budget' in addCondition() function